# How to set a dynamic base in Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my app, I'm trying to set it so my pages all show up after a sub-path, like for example: [www.website.com/my-app/homepage](http://www.website.com/my-app/homepage) or [www.website.com/my-app/profile](http://www.website.com/my-app/profile).

I know that you can set the base in vue-router to be "/my-app/", but if I don't know what the sub-path is, how can I make it so it dynamically knows what the sub-path is and lists the routes after that sub-path?

Comment: You need to explicitly provide it. How else a router could know which part of url is base? It's unclear why it's a problem in your case

Comment: the sub-path would be considered part of the route itself.  you probably want to use [nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes) from the sound of it.